# outlier slowness due to thread scheduling?

Tags: c++, linux, solaris

I'm running a multi-threaded C++ application on a Solaris 11. I guess it could happen on Linux as well, so I added 'Linux' tag. It's a quite powerful box, but also runs many applications. Occasionally it's really slow for my application to process a request dealt by a thread from a thread pool. Pseudocode is like below:

```
start = get_high_resolution_timer();
indexes = mymap.find(key);
for i in indexes:
    return_vector.push_back(cached_data[i]); // cached_data is vector<shared_ptr<Something> >
end = get_high_resolution_timer();

print (end-start)/1000000; // only care about milliseconds number
```

The whole dataset cached_data vector is not huge, and most of times indexes has either 1 or less than 10 indexes.

Normally the print is 0 because it takes less than 1ms. Occasionally it prints 10s or 100s milliseconds. I'm trying to figure out why it takes so long. It should not take couple of milliseconds to iterate the whole dataset and copy everything, I would think. The code might not be cpu cache friendly, but it should not have such a drastic impact, I guess. Is it more likely that OS decided to schedule another thread when current thread executes something between 'start' and 'end'? 
Thanks,
Derek

Comment: Rolling over limit numbers?

Comment: can you run your thread in higher priority?

Comment: https://vimeo.com/135065813 : While this video is really about issues with java garbage collection AND their product that fixes it, it has some interesting points about measuring latency and the distribution of delays that may be of some help/interest to you. Good luck.

Comment: If another thread runs at higher priority than your thread, it could hold your thread off the CPU for an extended period -- or if you're low on RAM, parts of your program might be waiting on I/O to be swapped back in.  Like Pooya says, the first thing you might try is raising your threads' priority to see if that helps any... but keep in mind that unless you are running on a real-time OS, there are no real guarantees made about when your threads will run -- everything is done on a "best effort" basis, which means that the occasionally holdoff is something that you'll need to expect.

Comment: *Does that mean I'd better pin my threads to CPU cores?*  No.  You don't know what's causing the variation in performance, and you haven't provided anywhere near enough information to get anything other than wild guesses as to what the cause could be.  We don't know what `indexes` is, we don't know what `cached_data` is other than a vector of *something*, and we don't even know what the hardware is, much less what else is running when you see the variations.